# How to hide an hyperlink on form load and show it upon some condition in jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox, hyperlink, smarty

I'm using PHP, Smarty and jQuery for my website. ActuMy smarty code snippet is as follows ally I want to hide an hyperlink( **tag**) on form load and display it depending on some condition. For your reference I'm putting my code below:
Smarty template code is as follows:

```
<div class="hor-form w25">
    <ul>
        {assign var='i' value=0}
        {foreach from=$all_subjects item=subjects}
          <li>
             <p class="custom-form"> 
                 <input type="checkbox" name="{$sheet_type}_subject_ids[]" id="{$sheet_type}_subject_{$subjects.subject_id}" value="{$subjects.subject_id}" {if in_array($subjects.subject_id, $subject_ids)}checked="checked"{/if} {if $op=='view'} disabled="disabled" {/if}onChange="get_subject_topics('{$sheet_type}', '{$subjects.subject_id}', '{$pack_id}'); return false;" class="custom-check"  />
                 <label>{$subjects.subject_name}{if in_array($subjects.subject_id, $subject_ids)}<a href="#">View-24</a>{/if}**<a class="view inline" href="#topics_{$subjects.subject_id}">View</a>**</label>
             </p>
            </li>
            {assign var='i' value=$i+1}
        {/foreach}
    </ul>
</div>
```

I've made the  tag bold which I want to hide on form load.
Now my issue is I want to make this link show only when it's corresponding checkbox is checked otherwise it should be kept as hidden. I tried the following jQuery script but it didn't work for me. Can you please help me in resolving this issue? Thanks in advance.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".view").hide();
  $(".{$sheet_type}_subject_{$subjects.subject_id}").is(":checked")(function(){
    $(".view").show();
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: It would be easier for you to debug, if you separated php/smarty from jQuery. For example, you can test the browser part here: http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Where is your .view class in your code?

Comment: @usmanallam:I've written the view class in my code.

Comment: Can you post the actual <script> and html markup that Smarty outputs?

Answer (score 1):

Didnt check it, but it seems you trying to select it with class instead id:

Class-Selctor:

```
 $(".{$sheet_type}_subject_{$subjects.subject_id}").is(":checked")(function(){
```

To ID:

```
 $("#{$sheet_type}_subject_{$subjects.subject_id}").is(":checked")(function(){
```

Ok, now that I looked closer to your code, it should be like this:

```
if($("#{$sheet_type}_subject_{$subjects.subject_id}").is(":checked")){
    $(".view").show();
}
```

Comment: It's not getting hide on load, the view links

Comment: Ist the Radio checked maybe??
otherwise, this seems to be an other problem, you really should do a example on jsFiddle.net ...